# What is the most elegant way in Golang to create JSON-RPC struct with params

Tags: go, json-rpc

I'm creating a Golang app to communicate with proprietary third-party JSON-RPC API that is sensitive to the order of elements.

Request should be sent using POST over HTTPS. Here is a request sample:

```json
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "ab_123",
  "params": [
    "ee0fe150-6648-11ed-bd23-c1392b9c96ae",
    "test@example.com",
    "NONE"
  ]
}
```

In API docs it's documented that first param should be `id`, second param is `email` and third param is `name`. There are may be **dozens of params**, some of them are optional (can have value `NONE`).

I'm looking for the **most elegant** way to create the request struct that will be readable and easy maintainable.

Here is what I have so far:

```golang
type APIRequest struct {
    Jsonrpc string   `json:"jsonrpc"`
    Method  string   `json:"method"`
    Params  []string `json:"params"`
}

var request = APIRequest{
    Jsonrpc: "2.0",
    Method:  "ab_123",
    Params: []string{
        "ee0fe150-6648-11ed-bd23-c1392b9c96ae",
        "test@example.com",
        "NONE",
    },
}
```

Comment: Is this for internal use only by your client app or are you trying to build a client lib that will be used by others?

Comment: For internal usage with possible code share inside of the team